# fancyBox - jquery: id= or class=?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Trying to make fancyBox working, I noticed a few things:

a) A copy/paste of the code from the ReadMe First doesn't work.

b) The syntax in the demo page of the fancyBox site is not the same one as the one in the ReadMe First and doesn't work (for me) either.

Syntax 1 is:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
</script>
```

and

```
<a href="large_1.jpg" class="fancybox" title="Sample title 1"><img src="small_1.jpg" /></a>
```

Syntax 2 is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#single_1").fancybox();
    });
</script>
```

and

```
<a href="large_1.jpg" id="single_1" title="Sample title 1"><img src="small_1.jpg" /></a>
```

I did include the load in the  section like this:

```
    <head>
    <!-- Add jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery-1.10.1.min.js">
    </script>

    <!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js">
    </script>
</head>
```

What did I do wrong, please?
When I click on a thumb the pix opens in the same window instead of in the pop-up.
Thanks.

Comment: Both syntax are probably correct as long as you have valid selector. I believe you might be wrong. The point of fancy box is to open within the same window instead of new pop up window.

Comment: Either of them should work. If you use an `id` then you can only bind a single element to fancybox in the same document (`id`s should be unique) while using *classes*, you can bind multiple elements to fancybox